# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need a little help sorting out where this error is coming from. According to the console, it is being thrown in jquery.min.js inside this function:

```
function buildParams( prefix, obj, traditional, add ) {
var name;

if ( jQuery.isArray( obj ) ) {

    // Serialize array item.
    jQuery.each( obj, function( i, v ) {
        if ( traditional || rbracket.test( prefix ) ) {

            // Treat each array item as a scalar.
            add( prefix, v );

        } else {

            // Item is non-scalar (array or object), encode its numeric index.
            buildParams(
                prefix + "[" + ( typeof v === "object" && v != null ? i : "" ) + "]",
                v,
                traditional,
                add
            );
        }
    } );

} else if ( !traditional && jQuery.type( obj ) === "object" ) {

    // Serialize object item.
    for ( name in obj ) {
        buildParams( prefix + "[" + name + "]", obj[ name ], traditional, add );
    }

} else {

    // Serialize scalar item.
    add( prefix, obj );
}
}
```

I believe that its specifically getting throw in this loop:

```
// Serialize object item.
for ( name in obj ) {
    buildParams( prefix + "[" + name + "]", obj[ name ], traditional, add );
}
```

I am using a slightly modified template that i got from the bootstrap website, but I obviously didn't modify this file and I'm assuming it should work out of the box. The error is getting triggered when I submit the following form:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
....
</form>
```

Which is controlled by the js.

```
$("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var firstName = $("#fname").val();
        var lastName = $("#lname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var cphone = $("#cphone").val();
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        var address = $("#address").val();
        var city = $("#city").val();
        var zip = $("#zip").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "iveTriedDifferentActionsHere",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                fname: fname,
                lname: lname,
                cphone: cphone,
                email: email,
                comment: comment,
                address: address,
                city: city,
                zip: zip
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        });
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});
```

I know that is a lot of code, but its the essentials. I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. I've tried different actions, different inputs, but I'm running out of ideas. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: where/how is `buildParams` invoked? what `obj` is passed to the function? does this data contain circular references (at any level)?

Comment: And you might want to add the full stacktrace

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've been digging and it looks like it might be related to a node_module. Getting rid of browser-sync got it further in the compile process before it hit a snag, but it looks like its still node modules.